# Collapse individual fieldset using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, fieldset

I have made a collapsible fieldset, but I have multiple fieldsets on the same page, and when I click one fieldset it collapses all of them, but I only want it to only collapse the one I clicked on, I have put the necessary code into Jsbin:
[Click here](http://jsbin.com/ijefax/3/edit)

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".leg").click(function () {
    $("div.proj").toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery you have set up applies the current click to all fieldsets, because you are requesting `$("div.proj")` for each fieldset.

You should use

```
$( this ).parent().find( '.proj' ).toggle();
```

Comment: @Henry-95 My fault, I didn't attentive read the HTML… corrected version above.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly with multiple .proj divs in the fieldset :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are selecting all the elements with class of `.proj`, you can use `this` that refers to your currently clicked element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".leg").click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: Even better would be to use `$(this).next('.proj')`, in case you later add other siblings between `.leg` and `.proj` elements.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens `next()` only selects the next sibling element, if there is another element between `.leg` and `prog` by using the selector or without the selector it only selects that element.

Comment: @undefined Woops, you're right. Ah well, `$(this).next()` will do fine then. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".leg").click(function () {              
         $(this).parent().children("div").toggle();
     });
});
```